# Accessing max/min of a list of numbers stored in numlist / local

Tags: stata, stata-macros

Is there a way to  access the maximum and minimum values stored in a numlist or local using something like `min()` and `max()` in Stata? I want to archive roughly something similar to this:

```
local test 5 10 25 50
local max_test = max(`test')
local min_test = min(`test')

foreach i in `test'{
qui gen x_`i' = `i'
}

reg y x_`min_test ' - x_`max_test '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for `max()` tells you that it accepts comma-separated arguments, so this will work:

```
local test 5 10 25 50
local test : subinstr local test " " ",", all 
local max_test = max(`test')
```

Naturally, you could put the commas in at the outset. Same story for the minimum.